# Find f(x) using the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Find $f(x)$ if
$$\int_0^{f(x)}t^2dt=\pi \cos(\pi x)$$
So what I did is , using the fundamental theorem of calc. part 2
$$\int_0^{f(x)}t^2dt=\pi \cos(\pi x) \Leftrightarrow \frac{f(x)^3}{3}-0=\pi \cos(\pi x)$$
so then
$$(3(\pi \cos(\pi x))^{1/3} = f(x)$$
is this correct?

Comment: it seems correct to me